# Rsync replaces files newer

Tags: rsync

I'm using rsync to migrate data from a server to another. Normaly it must replace files on new server only if they are older than source files. But i my cas it does the opposite! If I modifie a file on the source server, so the date is newer after, and I lanch my rsync command, it replaces only this file with the old one from the source...?? What am I missing??

Here is my command:

```
rsync -e ssh -avz --exclude="cache/*.*" --exclude="cache_*" --exclude="annuair/" --exclude="homes/" --exclude=".spamassassin/" --exclude=".usermin/" --exclude="cgi-bin/" --exclude="etc/" --exclude="fcgi-bin/" --exclude="logs/" --exclude="Maildir/" --exclude="tmp/" /home/mysite/ root@5.39.72.228:/home/mysite
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok found it: missing -u parameter. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it: missing -u parameter. Sorry.